# How to zero out all negative numbers in a group-by T-SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a T-SQL query where I want all negative quantities to be zeroed out.

```
SELECT 
p.productnumber, 
v.[Description],
SUM(i.Quantity) as quantity
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN ...
LEFT JOIN ...
LEFT JOIN ...
GROUP BY productnumber, [Description]
```

Basically if the sum is made up of 5, 5, -1, the result should be 5+5+0=10, and not (5+5+(-1)=9.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` statement

```
SUM(CASE WHEN i.Quantity < 0 THEN 0 ELSE i.Quantity END)
```

Or the proprietary `IIF` version

```
IIF(i.Quantity < 0, 0, i.Quantity)
```

Or a more obscure version

```
SUM(NULLIF(i.Quantity, -ABS(i.Quantity)))
```

or just exclude these rows altogether in the `WHERE` clause if they are not needed for any other purpose.

In Azure SQL Database you can now also use the [`GREATEST`](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/introducing-the-greatest-and-least-t-sql-functions/ba-p/2281726) function for this

```
GREATEST(i.Quantity,0)
```

Answer (score 5):

just filter out the ones you don't want...

```
WHERE quantity > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`SUM(CASE WHEN i.Quantity < 0 THEN 0 ELSE i.Quantity END) as quantity`

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered a long time ago but I thinks its worth mentioning that the zero floor formula is:

```
(x+|x|)/2
```

In SQL Server its:

```
SELECT (i.Quanity - ABS(i.Quanity))/2 AS Quanity
FROM ....
```

This comes up in a lot of computing scenarios.  Not sure if it's the most efficient way to do it in TSQL or if logic statements like `CASE` would be faster.  But this works 100% of the time every time.